# String values with spaces and '.' are getting converted to valid javascript datetime

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have following method to check if a date is valid or not

```
  private isValidDate(val: string) {
    return !isNaN((new Date(val)).getDate());
  }
```

Following conditions works fine

1. val = "6/24/2020 9:00:00 PM"

   `returns true`
2. val = "foo"

   `returns false`

Which is correct, but when my string has any decimal followed by any number the condition returns true `val = "foo 1"/"foo.1"/"foo-1"`
`returns true`

As `new Date("foo 1");` returns `Mon Jan 01 2001 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` which is a valid date time

So i there any way to check for valid dates which can be converted to `MMM DD YYYY hh:mm A` format

Comment: From the [manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date): "**Note**: Parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse(), which works the same way) is *strongly discouraged* due to browser differences and inconsistencies"

Comment: So, what is your question ? You want to check if input string is under the format `M/DD/YYYY H:MM:SS [AM/PM]` ?

Comment: @Cid i have updated the format `MMM DD YYYY hh:mm A`

Comment: @Nick so is there any valid way to check for dates in such scenarios, I'm using typescript

Comment: You can use regex, if you're fine with them. Or you can "manually" iterate the string and check its content